# Faster way to calculate pixel intensity(color value) without iterating through all the pixels in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am performing an operation in which I have to calculate sum of all pixel intensity, if the pixel value is >0. Currently, I am iterating through every pixel, which is slower. Can anyone please suggest a faster way to improve my code?

```
h, w = image.shape[:]
total_intensity = 0
for x in range(h):
    for y in range(w):
        if (image[x][y] > 0):
            total_intensity += image[x][y]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if image is a numpy array you can just do this:

```
total_intensity = image[image > 0].sum()
```

if you have a very big image you should worry about overflow issues in the sum, so I strongly suggest to first cast the image

```
image = np.int64(image)
```

Comment: @snehipachchigar: If this answer worked for you, instead of commenting "thanks", you should click the check mark underneath the vote count on the left of the answer. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). This is the SO way of saying thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

`total_intensity = sum(sum(filter(lambda i: i > 0, image[j])) for j in image)`

Where 0 your condition of minimum intensity